# Unresolved external symbol: QMetaObject const QwtPlotMagnifier::staticMetaObject

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I have a library that uses QwtPlotMagnifier, amongst other Qwt classes. I decided to subclass QwtPlotMagnifier so that I can emit a signal when the plot is rescaled. 
The library (mylib.lib) compiles, but the application using it is now complaining about an unresolved external related to the moc output of QwtPlotMagnifier.

I am linking qwt statically; so the requirement to have the preprocessor directive QWT_DLL in the lowest level library doesn't apply here.

Here's the error (the subclass is called PlotMagnifier):

```
mylib.lib(moc_PlotMagnifier.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QwtPlotMagnifier::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QwtPlotMagnifier@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
```

Nothing special about the subclass declaration:

```
#pragma once

#include "qwt_plot_magnifier.h"
/**
subclass of QwtPlotMagnifier to provide a signal when zooming is complete
*/
class PlotMagnifier : public QwtPlotMagnifier
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit PlotMagnifier(QWidget *w);
  virtual ~PlotMagnifier();
signals:
  void rescaled();
protected:
  virtual void rescale(double factor);  
};
```

I'm on visual studio 2013 fwiw. My application still includes qwtd.lib as it always has. This has got to be a stupid mistake on my part.. kickstart my brain please, someone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to .pro file to give the compiler a hint for an external symbol:

```
DEFINES += QWT_DLL
```

In the file `qwt_global.h` have the macro. Without this macro, the compiler will think this is an internal symbol.

Comment: I thought I had addressed both of those points above - I'm using MSVC to compile, so I have no CONFIG to setup (and I'm already succesfully using QWT throughout). Also I'm linking qwt statically, so I don't need QWT_DLL; in fact if I define this, I get errors all over the place

Comment: I take it back! After cleaning and rebuilding, I can compile just fine with QWT_DLL. This solves the problem, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you have all needed includes in you Visual Studio project.

`C/C++ / Additional Include Directories`
Here should be a path to `<qwt_dir\include>` be

`Linker / General / Additional Library Directories`
Here should be a path to `<qwt_dir\lib>` be

`Linker / Input`
Should include `qwtd.lib` (for `debug` configuration) and `qwt.lib` (for `release`)

Also, check that you have those entries in `Release` and `Debug` configurations, it is easy to configure only `Debug`, while working on `Release` configuration.

Also, check that you have `moc_*` file (something like `moc_plotmagnifier.cpp`) for your `PlotMagnifier` under `Generated Files` in your project view, sometimes Qt addin fails to add them.